# how to get data from multiple controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i want to fetch data from the 2 controllers. im getting data from one controller but im not getting data from the other controller.how to call the two controllers in one function

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("url")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.pir_data= response.data;
        $pir_Status_bit_= response.data.pir_staus;

        app.controller('watertankCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("url")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.watertank_data = response.data;
                $scope.wt_level = response.data.dataFrame;   
            });
        });
```

html

```
<div class="col-lg-4" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="our-team-main">
        <div class="team-front">
            <h4>Door Monitoring</h4>
            <a>PIR Smart Security</a>
            <hr />
            <p align="left">
                Door Status-  {{pir_Status_bit}} <br />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="watertankCtrl">
    <p align="left">
        Level - {{wt_level}} v<br />          
    </p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your data needs to come from multiple controllers it might be worth looking into turning one of them into a service instead.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to handle something like this would be using the `$q` service and using the `all` method. What's happening is that one of your `$http.get` promises is returning before the other. You want to wait for both to return.

Comment: can u share some link which will help to work with $q to call multiple controllers